# How to copy a partition over network

Tags: ssh, networking, file-copy, netcat

I want to copy a Windows 7 partition that came installed on my laptop to my desktop computer.

I've tried:

```
# bzip2 -c /dev/sda5 | nc 192.168.1.1 2222 # on laptop
# nc -l 2222 | bzip2 -d > /dev/sda1 # on desktop
```

But gparted tells me the partition is corrupted with a lot of error messages.

I also tried:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip -1 - | ssh user@hostname dd of=image.gz # on laptop
# dd if=image.gz | gunzip -1 - | dd of=/dev/sda5 # on desktop
```

It worked for a small partition (35 Mb), but didn't for larger ones (18Gb and 120Gb). The ssh pipe keeps breaking and one attempt that completed gave errors in gparted.

What would be a better way of copying the partitions?

Comment: What does "gpared tells me the partition is corrupted with a lot of error messages" mean?  Be specific.  Also you need to make sure that the destination partition is at least as large as the source.

Comment: dd, with netcat might give better speed? bzip2 is SLOW... `ssh -C` is easier to work with than a manual gzip... (at leas if you have dd directly writing to disk...) For the dd example, using `cat > image.gz` (via SSH) to write the file will reduce the number of layers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally copied using a tar pipe.

```
# cd /mnt/sda1/ && tar cf - * | nc 192.168.1.1 2222 # on laptop
# cd /mnt/sda5/ && nc -l 2222 | tar x # on desktop
```

Copying was way faster and seemed to work.

I wasn't able to boot in Windows 7 thought. I only saw a black screen when booting in it and the recovery partition freezes at Starting Windows.

I think that you need two licences to use Windows 7 on two computer so I don't think it would have worked.

Comment: Adding `gzip`/`gunzip` in fast-compression-mode in that pipe might help on low-bandwidth-connections. I would also have used "dd" with a block-level of at least 8K for reading (and for writing).

Answer (score 0):

Tar is not the way to copy bootable partitions. You'll get only your files, but not the on-disk structure. 
If you want to clone a disk, you'd better use Clonezilla. Often the boot manager is on the master boot record so you'll need to copy it, and windows7 has a hidden primary partition (about 100MB) which may be also needed. I'd reccomend you to just install virtualbox, create an image of the disk & restore it inside the virtual machine with CloneZilla. Thus you''ll have your windows7 in your VM.